Uplink signal modulation detection (drone related)
Can somebody help me and tell me if the UPLINK signal from a drone is an OFDM signal? I know that the DOWNLINK channel is OFDM, but i don't really find something related to UPLINK.
Can I infer on the uplink scheme from the downlink scheme? How are they related in radio equipment?

@webmarc I agree this doesn't appear to be directly related to amateur radio. But drone comms in general are within the scope of amateur radio. An example that I am following is Neptune which is a project of Open Research Institute. One can search for Open Research Institute to find YouTube videos and GitHub repos.

@webmarc although I wrote an answer, I can understand where you're coming from. For me, the question read "I have a bidirectional asymmetric transceiver system, can I infer on the uplink from knowing the modulation methods of the downlink?"; the drone aspect felt like "only meant as concrete use case for the general-radio question".

Seeing how close the question is to being closed, should we maybe edit it to that end, @webmarc?

@webmarc let's focus on the uplink vs downlink aspect then to keep them separate

Nice. Am deleting my earlier comments that are no longer relevant

Trying to answer this in a way that is on topic for a platform focused on amateur radio and general radio technology. Drones are not special there; otherwise, this would be off-topic.
There's no general statement to be made here. That will depend on the design of the individual device.
I never cease to repeat that, but: communications engineering is, like any field of engineering, a field where you can make choices of approach and parameters. You choose OFDM if the propagation and interference scenario and your communication demand say that is a wise choice.
Now, from the application (consumer drone) we can infer a few things:

Very likely, up- and downlink are in the same band
Because of 1., the RF scenario (interference, reflectors, path loss) are going to be similar

Furthermore, from the choice of OFDM for the downlink we can infer:

the downlink needs to transport so much data (video, maybe? you don't mention) that the downlink signal necessarily has enough bandwidth to exceed the coherence bandwidth of the channel (important concept if you're dealing with OFDM).

Sadly, because the link requirements are asymmetric (you need much more data per second in downlink than in uplink direction), there's no direct relationship between the transmission scheme for the two directions. Just because the downlink bandwidth is large doesn't mean the uplink bandwidth is! So, it doesn't necessarily make any sense to use OFDM in the uplink.
So, this answer applies:

you'll have to look at it.
I can't go into detail about every possible modulation, because
there's just too many. But typically, a look at the spectral
representation gives you an idea of whether you're dealing with

a straightforward single-carrier signal
a spread-spectrum signal or
a multicarrier signal.


OFDM is a multicarrier signal. In good SNR and given enough receive bandwidth, it's rather easy to recognize by it's "squarish" PSD shape.
There's companies whose capital is knowing how to automatically detect drones, the modulation scheme they use, get as much information from the signal as is available without knowing the cryptographic keys used, and to use the statistical properties of the modulation scheme to localize the drone and the remote control.
If you suspect there's an OFDM signal somewhere in your spectrum, there's mature algorithms to detect that and extract the OFDM parameters (subcarrier count and spacing, cyclic prefix length). gr-inspector integrates such. See its promo video.
